# autohotkey variables not updating on keypresses

Tags: variables, automation, scope, autohotkey, hotkeys

I have a number of hotkeys which go through various processes and sleep for certain periods of time to allow animations to be shown. I want to setup a variable to allow only 1 to activate at a time...so if I hit the first and then the second....the second doesn't do anything until the first completes. Similarly I don't want to double activate any of them by mashing the same key right after I first press it.

```
F4:ExitApp
#IfWinActive ahk_class notepad

a::
if (work:=true){
work:=false
soundbeep
;do something
sleep 1000
work:=true
}
return

b::
if (work:=true){
work:=false
soundbeep
;do something else
sleep 2000
work:=true
}
return
```

i.e. if I hit 'a'....'b' cannot activate until the sleep of 'a' ends. Nor should 'a' be able to activate a second time...at least not until its sleep ends and work=true again.

This leaves 2 problems. I need to first somehow specify the initial value of 'work=true'. I do not know how to do this in the traditional sense. Simply putting it at the top of the code doesn't work. Second problem, putting this in another key...like enter:: work:=true return....and pressing that key initially...this doesn't work as it allows b to beep while a is still in its sleep phase. So maybe the code above is flawed to begin with as well. Individual keys seem to respect themselves and not re-initialize until after the first instance has completed...so the beeps work if I just mash 1 key. Also I don't want to have to press enter to get the code to work after loading the script.

Is there an easy cheat here? Like in lua undeclared variables are automatically false... so I could just swap to if (work=false){...., I can't find any such behaviour with autohotkey though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here is a different solution that uses variable logic to allow or prevent hotkey commands from executing:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
work:=true
a::
if(work){
    work:=false
    soundbeep
    ;do something
    sleep 1000
    work:=true
}
return

b::
if(work){
    work:=false
    soundbeep
    ;do something else
    sleep 2000
    work:=true
}
return
```

---

### Update: Breakdown of how it works

First, the script begins in the [auto-execute](https://maul-esel.github.io/ahkbook/en/auto-execute-section.html) section. As summarized elegently by maul-esel

> When an AutoHotkey script launches, it just starts execution from the
> first line of your script. It continues from there line by line until
> it hits an end point. This is called the auto-execute section.

As such, by including `work:=true` in this section of the script, not only are we initializing the value of the variable before any hotkeys are triggered, we set the scope of `work` to be a global variable, accessible across different hotkeys.

The rest of the script is a bit more straightforward, where each hotkey is essentially (in pseudocode):

- When the hotkey is triggered
- if `work` is true

  - set `work` to false
  - Beep and etc.
  - Wait for some amount of time
  - Then set `work` back to true so that another command can be run
- End the hotkey

Comment: I'm used to scripts in terms of running just once or running in a gameloop (30 times a second). How does this one run exactly? I'm just curious mainly in terms of the work:=true part......does that only run one time...? I would think its like a gameloop and it keeps updating itself as being equal to true...overwriting any other assignments like to false. But this line works as if its an initial defined variable that is only run once. Is that the case and the script simply checks the if and hotkeys:: 100 times or so a second?

Comment: That's on me- I should have included an explanation for how the code worked when I wrote the answer. I've updated the post to include this @kite, so check it out and lmk if you have any questions.

Comment: Actually this code isn't always working. Its working for notepad. but it doesn't work while in applications like games. Thoughts? I've had to use the maxthreads method.

Comment: To make it work for other stuff, just remove the `#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad` from the top

Comment: ya i noticed that, that has been removed/updated accordingly. still not working. The rest of the script....as I've had it is working ingame and yes its all within that #IFWINACTIVE part..so its not that

Comment: Aight, could you please tell me which program(s) you want to use it with so that I can debug it?

Comment: Just in general if u remove the #IFWINACTIVE line and run it in the desktop and  press the keys....the soundbeep part fails

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235151/discussion-between-spyre-and-kite).

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do it would be to declare `#MaxThreads 1` at the top of your script.

As a side note, there appear to be a few other syntax errors in the script. For example, when comparing values (like in an `if` statement), you still use the regular, single `=` and not the assignment `:=`. Also, the `ahk_class` is case sensitive, and as such `#IfWinActive ahk_class notepad` should be replaced with `#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad`.

---

Updated Code (`Work` Variable logic was removed as it is no longer needed):

```
#MaxThreads 1

#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad

a::
soundbeep
;do something
sleep 1000
return

b::
soundbeep
;do something else
sleep 2000
return
```

Comment: yes this does seem to get at the desired behavior. still want to kno how to do it with variables tho.

Comment: Sure thing- I'll make another answer that solves it with variable gates